# ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D wrong location and size when zooming

Tags: winforms

ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D draws correctly at 100% but it is wrong if the zooming is less or more than 100%. It seems like it still draws with 100%. ControlPaint.DrawBorder is correct in all cases.

I found a similar post with the same problem but no solution yet: http://www.44342.com/dotnet-framework-f70-t8279-p1.htm and http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/differences-between-drawborder3d-and-drawborder-t1313989.html

Is this a known issue? Is there any workaround, other than using DrawBorder instead of DrawBorder3D?

**Update:** Here's a code sample for the scale transformation with DrawBorder3D and DrawBorder (the form has 2 buttons to zoom in and out, a PictureBox for the image and a label to display the current zoom). Watch what happens to the two borders when zooming: the red border adapts to the zoom factor but the 3D border won't change.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Image image;
    float currentZoom = 100.0f;
    float zoom = 1.0f;
    const int zoomIncrement = 10;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        const string fileName = @"C:\30400988_1506.jpg";
        image = Image.FromFile(fileName);
        pictureBox.Paint += pictureBox_Paint;
        lblCurrentZoom.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    private void pictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(zoom, zoom);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);

        var units = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
        var rectangle = Rectangle.Round(image.GetBounds(ref units));

        ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(e.Graphics, rectangle, Border3DStyle.Sunken);
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, rectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
    }

    private void btnZoomIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetZoom(currentZoom + zoomIncrement);
        pictureBox.Invalidate();
        lblCurrentZoom.Text = "current zoom: " + zoom.ToString("p");
    }

    private void btnZoomOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetZoom(currentZoom - zoomIncrement);
        pictureBox.Invalidate();
        lblCurrentZoom.Text = "current zoom: " + zoom.ToString("p");
    }

    private void SetZoom(float zoomPercentage)
    {
        zoom = zoomPercentage / 100.0f;
        if (zoom < 0.1f)
        {
            zoom = 0.1f;
        }
        currentZoom = zoom * 100.0f;
    }
}
```

I didn't have much time and I can't post our productive code so this example is adapted from http://tjclifton.com/2012/03/13/zooming-an-image-in-windows-forms/.

Comment: What do you mean by zooming, and what are those percentage values you're talking about? Do they mean windows font settings?

Comment: Let's say I have a Windows Forms application with one form with an image with a 3D border around it. The normal view is 100% and if I would draw the 3D border with DrawBorder3D around the image then it would look correct. Let's say that I zoom in towards the image to 50% so the image appears closer or zoom out to 200% so that the image appears more far away, and I would draw the 3D border around the image with DrawBorder3D then the image would appear smaller/bigger according to the zoom factor but the 3D border is not adapted to the zoom factor.

Comment: Sorry, still am not clear how are you zooming. How do you implemented zoom? Posting some code to reproduce the problem can make us better to understand the problem.

Comment: We're using Graphics.TranslateTransform and Graphics.ScaleTransform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the DrawBorder3D method ignores all graphics transformations. e.g. in the following code, the first rectangle is not rotated but the second one is.

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(30.0f);
        var rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 200);
        var rect2 = new Rectangle(300,10,100,200);
        // ignores the rotate transformation
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(e.Graphics, rect, Border3DStyle.SunkenOuter, Border3DSide.All);
        // draws with rotate transformation
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, rect2, Color.Black, ButtonBorderStyle.Outset);
    }
```

I guess you could read the zoom factor from the current world Transformation Matrix (if you only have zooming) and scale manually the rectangle which you are using to draw the 3d border...something along the lines of

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(1.5f,1.5f);
        var rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 200);
        var rect2 = new Rectangle(300, 10, 100, 200);
        // scale the rectangle
       var scaleFactor = e.Graphics.Transform.Elements[0];

        rect.X = (int)(rect.X * scaleFactor);
        rect.Y = (int)(rect.Y * scaleFactor);
        rect.Width = (int)(rect.Width * scaleFactor);
        rect.Height = (int)(rect.Height * scaleFactor);

        ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(e.Graphics, rect, Border3DStyle.SunkenOuter, Border3DSide.All);
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, rect2, Color.Black, ButtonBorderStyle.Outset);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I use the Graphics.Transform matrix to get the current scale factor and apply it to the the location and size. It works great.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why that doesn't work. Whatever you do with `Graphics` instance gets scaled, `DrawBorder` just draws border with `Graphics.DrawRectangle` method internally(which gets scaled)  as opposed to `DrawBorder3D` which uses [DrawEdge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162477%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) win32 api (which doesn't).

As a workaround you could manually scale the rectangle and pass it to `DrawBorder3D`.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    int scaleX = 2;
    int scaleY = 2;

    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    g.ScaleTransform(scaleX, scaleY);//Scale

    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(10, 10, 60, 40);
    g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Gray, rectangle);

    var scaledRectangle = Scale(rectangle, scaleX, scaleY);//Scale the border manually
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(g, scaledRectangle);//Note the use of scaled rectangle instead of actual rectangle.
}

private Rectangle Scale(Rectangle rectangle, int scaleX, int scaleY)
{
    if (rectangle.IsEmpty)
    {
        return rectangle;
    }

    rectangle.X *= scaleX;
    rectangle.Y *= scaleY;
    rectangle.Width *= scaleX;
    rectangle.Height *= scaleY;

    // If the scale in the X dimension is negative, we need to normalize X and Width
    if (scaleX < 0)
    {
        // Make X the left-most edge again
        rectangle.X += rectangle.Width;

        // and make Width positive
        rectangle.Width *= -1;
    }

    // Do the same for the Y dimension
    if (scaleY < 0)
    {
        // Make Y the top-most edge again
        rectangle.Y += rectangle.Height;

        // and make Height positive
        rectangle.Height *= -1;
    }

    return rectangle;
}
```

Scale method is taken from [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/src/Base/System/Windows/Rect.cs)